# Files in /etc/init - are all files executed or just the ones with conf extension?

Tags: boot, init

I have some files in `/etc/init` that I am still testing. As far as I know all files in this directory are executed on boot.

My question is: does it apply to every `*.conf` file or to *all* of the files in the directory? What if I want to backup one file: would `/etc/init/someinit.conf.20130507` be executed?

I checked the `man` page but could not find any clear explanation about it.

These are my `OS` and `init` informations:

```
$ uname -a
Linux me 3.5.0-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 11 18:51:59 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.10, Quantal Quetzal"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu quantal (12.10)"
VERSION_ID="12.10"

$ init --version
init (upstart 1.5)
Copyright (C) 2012 Scott James Remnant, Canonical Ltd.
```

Comment: To what version of what OS are you referring?

Comment: This depends very much on which `init` daemon you're using (or which OS and distribution). For example, `upstart` init (Ubuntu) and `openrc` init (Gentoo) behave very differently.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 12.10, @JonathanBen-Avraham . Just updated the post with this info.

Comment: It is `upstart 1.5`, @jpaugh. Just updated the post with this info.

Comment: I'm pretty sure upstart only runs files ending with `.conf`, but that's from reading the man pages, and I'm out of touch with Ubuntu.

Comment: Just found the solution. I post it as an answer in case it is useful for somebody. Thanks, @jpaugh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the answer: in my upstart 1.5 it just works with `*.conf` files.

Test:

I created two files `/etc/init/zzservice.conf` and `/etc/init/yyservice.conf.20130507`. First one would work while the second not. It worked when I changed the name of the second to `/etc/init/yyservice.conf`, that is, finishing with `.conf`.

```
# cat /etc/init/zzservice.conf 

script
  exec su - root -c 'echo "this is a test" > /tmp/testservice'
end script


start on (started network-interface
          or started network-manager
          or started networking)

stop on (stopping network-interface
         or stopping network-manager
         or stopping networking)


# service zzservice restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
zzservice start/running, process 5839
# 
# service yyservice restart
yyservice: unrecognized service
# 
# mv yyservice.conf.20130507 yyservice.conf
# 
# service yyservice restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
yyservice start/running, process 5866
#
```